# Apache Require env is ignored

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have following simple directive in .htaccess, I like to allow access by env, condition:

```
SetEnv ABC 1
<RequireAny>
  Require env ABC 
</RequireAny>
```

Seems to me very simple, but Access is always rejected:

```
AH01626: authorization result of Require env ABC: denied
[Thu Apr 10 14:33:19.091773 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 6583] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 127.0.0.1:49697] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied
```

Any ideas, please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SetEnvIf`:

> The internal environment variables set by this directive are set after most early request processing directives are run, such as access control and URI-to-filename mapping. If the environment variable you're setting is meant as input into this early phase of processing such as the `RewriteRule` directive, you should instead set the environment variable with `SetEnvIf`.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html#setenv